# Make Google Analytics anonymous

Tags: google-analytics

Because of the AVG law, I wondered how it was possible to make IP addresses anonymous, for Google Analytics .JS code(Deleting the last set of digits).

I am aware that it is somewhat explained in Google's documentation, but it is always handy to ask.

The documentation refers to an 'anonymizeIp' class that can be added to the tracking. But how can you do this best if you want to use it in this script?

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xx');
</script>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gat#_gat._anonymizeIp

Answer (score 0):

I found a great article on a German website that shows the various methods to accomplish this task.

Update your config line like this:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

Source: https://www.metrika.de/blog/web-analytics/google-analytics-anonymizeip/